# scatterplot in python for different group, and the variables inside the group should have different colors

Tags: python, statistics, scatter-plot

I want three scatter plots in one graph, plotting between ORI_PL& ORI_ML and the similarly for the other groups. and the markers for each group is different. But the colors of the markers should follow the colors mentioned on the left-hand side, how do I do that? I wrote code but could not make the color different for each inside the group.

```
plt.scatter(sample_data.Image2,sample_data.ORI_PL,sample_data.ORI_ML,marker="o",c='gray')
plt.scatter(sample_data.Image2,sample_data.ORILOWER_PL,sample_data.ORILOWER_ML,marker="+", c='b'    )
plt.scatter(sample_data.Image2,sample_data.ORIHIGH_PL, sample_data.ORIHIGH_ML, marker ="_", c='r'   )
#palette['BLUE','YELLOW','GREEN','RED','ORANGE']
plt.xlabel("Physical Luminance")
plt.ylabel("Matched Luminance")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

[image][image]I can make the 3 plots in the same graph.. but I want each group to have different markers, but the color of the markers should be different for every value in each group. I want the colors as mentioned in the data of the image attached

Comment: Image 2  ORI_PL ORI_ML
BLUE 0.153 0.153
YELLOW 0.71 0.71
GREEN 0.585 0.585
RED 0.578 0.578
ORANGE 0.574 0.574
This is the data, so i want the scatter for the two group, with same marker but the color of each point should be the colors mentioned in the left hand side